# handling unique urls for each user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to provide each users of website a separate url but all users will see same pages.
www.myweb.com/user1/logon
www.myweb.com/user2/logon

similary
www.myweb.com/user1/wellcome
www.myweb.com/user2/wellcome

Is there any mechanism in asp.net mvc so that I can handle such things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't a route working for you:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "{user}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

You might also need a custom Authorize attribute to ensure that the user token coming from the url matches the one in the authentication cookie or `user1` could type in the url `user2` and see his pages, but if this is not a requirement for you you don't need to.